# React-i18next and cached translation files

Tags: reactjs, browser-cache

I'm using "react-i18next" to translate my Website and the translation files are in "/public/locales/{en|fr}/translation.json".

Problem: the files are cached and therefore when I update the translation values, the changes are not applied except if I clean my browser caches.

I guess, the solution is to add a hash in the name of these translation files during the start/build. This is what React already does for files in '/src' folder. How can I achieve that ? It seems that 'react-scripts start/build' abstract all the Webpack configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can host your translations on a dedicated path with the help of [i18next-http-backend](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend), like described [here](https://locize.com/blog/react-i18next/#separate).

Alternatively, you could also make use of a professional CDN service like locize and fetch the translations via [i18next-locize-backend](https://github.com/locize/i18next-locize-backend), like described [here](https://locize.com/blog/react-i18next/#how-look).

Comment: I already use i18next-http-backend and this is why my translation files are in '/public/locales/{en|fr}/translation.json' exactly like described in your link.
I already have a CDN where I have a HTTP Cache-control on every files. That seems a good idea for performance but I just want to handle modification case by automatically adding a hash in the translation file names. I just don't know how to do it.